# Can I scale GPU frequency?

Tags: gpu

My laptop is Thinkpad T400 with Ubuntu 12.04. My GPU is ATI graphics module, if I am not mistaken. I wonder how I can scale GPU frequency? software and/or shell script are acceptable.

For cpu frequency, I use cpufreq to set the cpu frequency to the lowest 0.8GHz from five scales, and it also offers several auto-adjusted options (performance, on demand, power save, conservative). Are there alikes for GPU?

Answer (score 4):

- AMD/ATI

The proprietary graphics driver `ATI Catalyst Linux` (also known as `fglrx`) supports GPU frequency scaling (`ATI Overdrive`). You can alter the frequencies via `aticonfig` command, e.g:

```
aticonfig --od-setclocks=350,150
```

Run `aticonfig --help` or visit [this page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Aticonfighelp) for the complete documentation.
Also, note that

> there is no guarantee that the attempted clock values will succeed
>   even if they lay inside the theoretical range.

Another tool that works with the proprietary driver is [AMDOverdriveCtrl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amdovdrvctrl/):

[image]

---

- nVidia

The proprietary graphics driver has *limited*<sup>1</sup> support for GPU frequency scaling via `Coolbits` options. Add

```
Option "CoolBits" "1"
```

or, for Fermi and newer cards (see [this article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?px=MTY1OTM&page=news_item))

```
Option "CoolBits" "8"
```

to the nVidia device section in `xorg.conf` (detailed description for each option in the [oficial nVidia driver documentation](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.46/README/xconfigoptions.html)). This practically "unlocks" the `Clock Frequencies` page in `NVIDIA X Server Settings` where you can enable overclocking/downclocking:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `nvidia-settings` in terminal, e.g.

```
nvidia-settings --assign "[gpu:0]/GPUOverclockingState=1" --assign "[gpu:0]/GPU2DClockFreqs=350,550" --assign="[gpu:0]/GPU3DClockFreqs=500,800"
```

to enable frequency scaling and set core and memory frequencies for 2D & 3D profiles. Or

```
nvidia-settings --assign "[gpu:0]/GPUOverclockingState=0"
```

to revert to default frequencies. Run `nvidia-settings --query all` to get a list of all the attributes (like [this one here](http://pastebin.com/cEMsyxtq)).

Another tool that works with the official driver is [nvclock](http://www.linuxhardware.org/nvclock/):

[image]

<sup>1. *On mobile GPUs, limited clock manipulation support is available when "1" is set in the "Coolbits" option value: clocks can be lowered relative to the default settings, but overclocking is not supported due to the thermal constraints of notebook designs.*</sup>

---

- Intel

Those who have an Intel Sandybridge/Ivybridge GPU and the right hardware should be able to manipulate clock speeds via `/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_*_freq_mhz` files. Details on [Daniel Vetter's page](http://blog.ffwll.ch/2013/03/overclocking-your-intel-gpu-on-linux.html).