# Why does my CPU disregard the maximum frequency set by e.g. cpupower and how can I keep my CPU from getting too hot?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, intel, cpu-frequency

I am using Debian 10 (buster), `4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux` on my Lenovo T530 laptop which has a `i7-3630QM`. It has been many years since I bothered with frequency scaling and temperature but as of late it has become a bit of a problem.

When I try to run CPU intensive applications the CPU can get very hot for longer periods of time, I am talking above 100°C. Now this laptop is more than eight years old and I'm not sure how much longer it's going to last so I want to

1. Have it last as long as possible and
2. Reduce the noise pollution since the fan gets rather loud at high loads and temperatures.

Years ago there were several governors that could be used to do this so I was surprised that now there is only `powersave` and `performance`. I tried to use `cpupower` to set a maximum frequency of e.g. 2.4GHz: `cpufreq-set -u 2.4GHz`.

Unfortunately that does not seem to really work. `cpupower frequency-info` reports

```
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
```

but when I start a CPU intensive applications (especially one that is in need of 3D graphics acceleration), in my case the game "Stellaris", the CPU gets really hot nevertheless, which is not surprising since `cpupower frequency-info` reports

```
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 3.30 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
```

which actually contradicts itself.

Now this issue has been discussed e.g. in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/424602/421363) issue and the author resolves it in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424801/421363). However, some people have commented that this does not work. In my case it does not work either. Another poster in this issue writes in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635137/421363) that this does not work either and actually links to a kernel [document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt) where it states that it is actually not possible to reliably set the frequency.

The fans of my laptop have been cleaned recently and new thermal paste has been applied but as I stated this machine is old and gets hot nevertheless. A different poster [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459924/421363) setting the maximum load to a lower percentage, which actually works but does not rectify my problem since the CPU gets really hot nevertheless.

Does anyone know of a different, reliable way to limit the CPU frequency? In the aforementioned example, Stellaris, I think I noticed that the CPU tried to limit the frequency to the set value of 2.4GHz while the game was loading and while I was in the main menu. Once I loaded a save file and was in the game itself it spiked to its maximum frequency. Is it possible that the application itself overrides these values?

Does anyone know of any other way to throttle the CPU from reaching such high temperatures? E.g. is it possible to set a lower temperature threshold for when the CPU starts throttling itself?

Comment: Please try this script: https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/cpumode via `cpumode -s ` It's written by me, it's safe to use.

Comment: If you don't mind installing an extra package, I can recommend [`corectrl`](https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks for the script. I tried using it but it seems I run into the same problem i.e. I can set a frequency but when loading an application that places a heavy load on the CPU/GPU the frequency limit is disregarded and the CPU runs hot anyway. @telometto I don't mind installing an extra package. Unfortunately corectrl is not available in Debian. I downloaded the source and compiled it (that step worked) but when I try to start the application nothing happens. I get `kf5.kauth: Tried to start an invalid action` and nothing more. Thanks for your sugestions, though!

Comment: Try using acpi-cpufreq intead of intel_pstate : https://silvae86.github.io/2020/06/13/switching-to-acpi-power/

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks, I think this did work. Strange that the intel_pstate driver is so weird.

Comment: You may want to file a bug report against intel_pstate along with the steps to repro the issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Power%20Management  Other users of similar CPUs will be grateful. Either the driver is not compatible with your IvyBridge CPU or it's missing something to support it. In any case, a bug report is really important.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Do you want to write that as the answer to the question? I am not yet very familiar with StackOverflow. Do you really think I should file the bug report. The kernel documentation even states that the intel pstate driver does not necessarily does what the user wants. I probably should, though.

Comment: Intel claims the intel_pstate driver supports all Intel Core CPUs starting with Sandy Bridge which is clearly not the case for you. A bug report could be useful.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not sure. I mean the kernel module did load and cpupower said that the driver used was intel_pstate. It's just that the behaviour of the driver was either misleading or maybe I just expected something that it didn't support. cpupower claimed you could set the maximum frequency to a certain value and that was true - just at some point the driver decided it knew better what to do. I am not defending intel_pstate, though. It's really strange behaviour and I'm going to go with acpi_cpufreq now, I just didn't know there was this possibility.

Comment: From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html : *"intel_pstate is a part of the CPU performance scaling subsystem in the Linux kernel (CPUFreq). It is a scaling driver for the Sandy Bridge and later generations of Intel processors. Note, however, that some of those processors may not be supported. [To understand intel_pstate it is necessary to know how CPUFreq works in general, so this is the time to read CPU Performance Scaling if you have not done that yet.]"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) I was able to resolve the problem. He wrote in a comment

> Try using acpi-cpufreq intead of intel_pstate : https://silvae86.github.io/2020/06/13/switching-to-acpi-power

and that did the trick.

I had to install the `acpi_cpufreq` driver (in my case it was already installed) via `apt-get`

```
apt-get install acpi-support acpid acpi
```

and edit `/etc/default/grub` by adding `intel_pstate=disable` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, like so (in my case):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash debug intel_pstate=disable"
```

Then run `update-grub` and restart the machine. Consequently the `intel_pstate` driver is not used anymore and `acpi_cpufreq` is used in its stead. Apart from having many more governors to chose from (you can read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_governors) about them) and most of all I can now turn on the `ondemand` governor and set a minimum and maximum frequency. And it is kept that way. In my case I used

```
cpupower frequency-set -g ondemand -d 1.2GHz -u 2.0GHz
```

and so far the machine hasn't gotten too hot.

[edit]
After still experiencing temperature problems I figured out what the problem is. It's the GPU frequency and the fact that this problem still occurred when using 3D applications. In `/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_ring_freq_table` you can see the max frequency the GPU can run at corresponding to a max CPU frequency. After setting the CPU frequency the GPU frequency has to be adjusted as well in `/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz` and in `/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_boost_freq_mhz`.

Comment: I'm still looking forward to a bug report from you :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like switching to acpi_cpufreq did not solve this problem. I now upgraded to Debian testing where I have also access to cpupower-gui and the system just disregards what I choose. I can switch to powersave, 1.2 GHz to 2.0 GHz and it does not work. The CPU still clocks at maximum.

Comment: I think I finally found the problem. This behaviour occurs when using 3D applications, i.e. when the internal GPU is being used. The problem was the GPU frequency. In `/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_ring_freq_table` you can see the max frequency the GPU can run at corresponding to a max CPU frequency. After setting the CPU frequency the GPU frequency has to be adjusted as well in `/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz` and in `/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_boost_freq_mhz`.

Comment: This sounds quite ... unusual. I've had lots of laptops and PCs with Intel integrated graphics and CPU frequency could always be regulated independently from iGPU frequency.

Comment: I agree, it's quaint. The CPU freq I set is considered when not running 3D applications that use the video card. That is what lead me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930372/setting-intel-gpu-limits-in-ubuntu-17-04-no-longer-works) issue and [this](https://blog.ffwll.ch/2013/03/overclocking-your-intel-gpu-on-linux.html) link as well as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163016/can-i-scale-gpu-frequency) issue. GPU clock is tied to CPU for some reason and certain GPU clocks can be only achieved by a min. CPU clock. Is that a bug/feature? Shall I still file that bug report?

Comment: I would still file a bug report. Maybe it's a known issue but in this case documentation has to be updated and the driver has to issue a warning which is definitely not the case for you.